# Partly invoke validation process on some Activerecord object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a situation where `User has_one :address` and `Address belongs_to :user`.
I need to be able to validate the address object in these cases:

**After a user has signed up**, he has an option to partly fill in the address form. In this state I would like to validate for example `validates :phone_number, :postal_code, numericality: true` but the user can leave the field blank if he wants to.

**When user is making a purchase** he has to complete the address form. And all the fields have to be validated by `validates presence: true` + previous validations.

I understand that one approach would be to attach another parameter to the form (i.e.`full_validation`) and then add a custom validation method that would check for this parameter and then fully validate all attributes.

I was just wondering is there a more code efficient and easier way to do this.

So far I have only found ways to validate some attributes (see[this blog post](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2010/06/partial-validation-in-rails/)) but I have not yet found suggestions on how to invoke part of the validation process for certain attributes.

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :address, inverse_of: :user
end

#app/models/address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :address

   validates :phone_number, :postal_code, numericality: true, if: ["phone_number.present?", "postal_code.present?"]
   validates :x, :y, :z, presence: true, unless: "user.new_record?"
end
```

--

**After a user has signed up**

Use [`if`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-string-with-if-and-unless) to determine if the `phone_number` or `postal_code` are present.

This will only validate their numericality if they exist in the submitted data. Whether the `User` is new doesn't matter.

--

**When user is making a purchase**

To make a purchase, I presume a `User` has to have been created (otherwise he cannot purchase). I used the [`user.new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F) method to determine whether the user is a new record or not.

---

Ultimately, both my & `@odaata`'s answers allude to the use of [conditional evaluation (`if` / `unless`)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) to determine whether certain attributes / credentials warrant validation.

The [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F) cover the issue in depth; I included `inverse_of` because it gives you access to the associative objects (allowing you to call `user.x` in `Address`).

If you give more context on how you're managing the `purchase` flow, I'll be able to provide better conditional logic for it.

Answer (score 1):

For your first use case, you can use the `:allow_blank` option on `validates` to allow the field to be blank, i.e. only validate the field if it is not blank?.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank

For both use cases, you can tell Rails exactly when to fire the validations using the `:if`/`:unless` options. This is known as Conditional Validation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

For `Address`, you might try something like this:

```
class Address
  belongs_to :user
  validates :phone_number, :postal_code, numericality: true, allow_blank: true, if: new_user?

  def new_user?
    user && user.new_record?
  end      
end
```

This gives you an example for your first use case. As for the second, you'll want to use conditional validation on `User` to make sure an address is present when the person makes a purchase. How this is handled depends on your situation: You could set a flag on `User` or have that flag check some aspect of `User`, e.g. the presence of any purchases for a given user.

```
class User
  has_one :address
  has_many :purchases
  validates :address, presence: true, if: has_purchases?

  def has_purchases?
    purchases.exists?
  end
end
```